# Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class

Tags: java, android, debugging

I'm using 2 phones for debuging and 1 phone is showing my activity fine and the other dose the error, how can I repair it + how can I handle it for another users to not have crashes?

the crash:

```
07-19 19:51:33.614 18679-18679/itay.finci.org.allerwarn E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: itay.finci.org.allerwarn, PID: 18679
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{itay.finci.org.allerwarn/itay.finci.org.allerwarn.intro.IntroActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.miz.introactivity.NextDoneButton
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.miz.introactivity.NextDoneButton
```

edit:
thanks for AndroidStudio decompiler I adding the done.xml that dose all the errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="36dp"
android:height="36dp"
android:viewportHeight="48"
android:viewportWidth="48">

<group android:name="done_group">

    <path
        android:name="done"
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M18 32.34L9.66 24l-2.83 2.83L18 38l24-24-2.83-2.83z" />

</group>

</vector>
```

edit 2:
the layout xml out of the library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/title_padding_left"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/title_padding_left"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/title_padding_right"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/title_padding_right"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_height"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/skip_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left|start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/skip"
        android:textColor="@color/skip_text_color"
        style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.miz.introactivity.NextDoneButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right|end"
        android:background="@drawable/next_done_button_selector"
        />

</FrameLayout>

</merge>
```

Comment: you can handle it with a try/catch. as far as repairing...can you show your code?

Comment: you have an error in your layout for the IntroActivity.  can you add this xml to your question and state the package and class for NextDoneButton

Comment: @petey  the NextDoneButton is not in my side, I have a library that add it

Answer (score 0):

its an error in your IntroActivity. InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.miz.introactivity.NextDoneButton

More than likely; this could be due to any LARGE images you are using and the device is simply out of memory to display it. Try resizing the image to make the size of it smaller

Comment: I'm using a library that make the vector for me, I can't change it/

Comment: What about the activity xml? @Finci